# What is the fastest way to add a lot of nodes/edges to a NetworkX graph programmatically?

Tags: networkx

I need to quickly create a large NetworkX Graph, with data coming from a query against some database, returning a lot of data. I gear adding nodes and edges one by one would be ridiculously slow. Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 0):

To add edges, use [`Graph.add_edges_from`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.add_edges_from.html).

To add nodes, use [`Graph.add_nodes_from`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.add_nodes_from.html).

Comment: I had the same question, I tried that, and it's not faster. Looking at the code shows it's still a python loop that does as much work as `add_edges`. (Actually it does slightly more work.)